# Getting array's matching value on joined table

Tags: arrays, join, presto

I'm currently on a Presto database and have an array of ID on TableA: `["A", "B", "C", "D"]`

How can I use a joined mapping TableB (below) to return an array with the corresponding color? `["red", "yellow", "blue", "brown"]`

```
|  ID  | color  |
|---------------+
|  A   | red    |
|  B   | yellow |
|  C   | blue   |
|  D   | brown  |
```

I was planning to unnest my array and then perform my JOIN but I'm working with a lot of columns already so I was wondering if there could be an easier way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Array functions can be used in join conditions. This was not immediately obvious to me either, but it makes it straightforward to write queries like you are looking for. For example:

```sql
SELECT
  user_colors.user_id,
  ARRAY_AGG(color_lookup.color)
FROM user_colors
JOIN color_lookup ON CONTAINS(user_colors.color_ids, color_lookup.id)
GROUP BY user_colors.user_id
```

Assuming that `user_colors` was the table with the array of color ids, your TableA.

---

After writing the above, I started thinking there must be a way to get a MAP based on the lookup table. And there is! Although, it is a little strange because, from what I can tell, it has to be unconditionally joined to every row. Structured as a sub-select, it looks like this:

```sql
SELECT
  TRANSFORM(color_ids, x -> color_map[x])
FROM TableA
JOIN (
  SELECT MAP_AGG(id, color) AS color_map
  FROM TableB
) ON 1 = 1
```

But it can also be structured as a CTE or WITH clause:

```sql
WITH color_lookup AS (
    SELECT MAP_AGG(id, color) AS color_map
    FROM TableB
)
SELECT
  TRANSFORM(color_ids, x -> color_map[x])
FROM TableA
JOIN color_lookup ON 1 = 1
```